# Search In a column which stores an array

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my table professional_infos table there is one column primary_skill_ids which stores an array of skills for particular user. I want to list all the user who has some particular skill sets.
example -

```
user1 has primary_skill as ["1","3","5","9","4"]
user2 has primary_skill as ["1","7","9","4"]
user3 has primary_skill as ["1","4","11"]
user3 has primary_skill as ["7","9","4"]
user4 has primary_skill as ["1","7","9"]
user5 has primary_skill as ["7","9"]
```

now I want to perform a search like get me all the users which have any or all of the skill primary_skill_ids as ["1","4]

please help me to write a rails query to do so.

I have done like the following

```
     wildcard_search = "%#{params[:search_title]}%"
            # key skills and best in search
      @key_skills=[] 
     @key_skills.each do | sk |
     # here I am thinking of looping through the ids and do a where clause on column primary_skill_ids but dont know its good idea


            end
```

Comment: You should use a [many-to-many relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) instead.

Comment: I am doing a search functionality. I have defined associations between professional_infos and skills

Comment: Could you show your models and / or database schema? _"one column primary_skill_ids which stores an array of skills"_ sounds more like a serialized string than an association.

Comment: yes @Stefan its a serialized string. which stores data as array
 serialize :primary_skill_ids, Array  I have done like this to store it

Comment: That's why I said _"You should use a many-to-many relationship instead"_. Serialized columns are fine if you process the data in your application. They are not meant to be processed via SQL.

Comment: any other alternative to perform search. as i cant go back to remove serialize and perform many to many relationship

Comment: _"i cant go back"_ – why not? It might take some time to write the migration and adapt the code, but it will surely pay off.

Comment: So need making one more table for storing relation between user ,professional info and primary skill. and define association between professional info and primary skill as many to many ?

Answer (score 3):

Serializing relation data in a string column violates the very idea of a relational database - which is that you have foreign key columns that point to other tables. Using array* or string types in the DB for associations is a really bad idea:

- It is highly inefficient to search strings compared to an indexed column containing integers or uiids.
- There is no referential integrity enforced by foreign key constraints.
- Its not how ActiveRecord works - which means you'll be wasting time by fighting the framework.

Instead you want to create a [many-to-many association through a join table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

In this example we are using a table named `user_skills` to join the two models:

```
create_table "user_skills", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "skill_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["skill_id"], name: "index_user_skills_on_skill_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_skills_on_user_id", using: :btree
end
```

You can then setup UI controls by using the collection helpers:

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :skill_ids, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PUT|PATCH /users/:id
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def user_params 
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(skill_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Comment: You'll have to create a migration or rake task that iterates through the existing records and splits the string and creates a join table row for each. If you need help with that task ask it as a seperate question and make sure to include the schema and any relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports standard SQL arrays and the standard [any](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html) operation syntax:

So, you can use an SQL like

```
where name ilike any (array['%val1%', '%val2%'])
```

Using Rails it can be written like:

```
User.where('primary_skill ilike any (array[?])', ["1","4"] )
```

**Additional info:**

In your situation you can use "ILIKE", or "LIKE", but the difference is:

- "ILIKE" is case-insensitive
- "LIKE" is case-sensitive.

Usage of wildcards (`%` from  `'%val1%'`) are detailed [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-wildcards.htm)